# Gallery with setScaleX/Y on children

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a gallery feeded by custom adapter using custom views as elements. I need these elements to be scaled by 70% by default. **The problem is that gallery behaves like they are at 100% size with 30% transparent padding = spacing between elements are just big.** For better understanding I attached two images with elements scaled to 100% and 70%.

[Elements scaled to 100%](http://www.lost-bytes.com/junk/gallery_100p.png)

[Elements scaled to 70%](http://www.lost-bytes.com/junk/gallery_70p.png)

I cannot hardcode the setSpacing as this would behave weird on different resolutions. I tried setSpacing(0) with no luck. **How can I achieve that gallery would behave like the elements are small (70%) and not the original size?**

I'm scaling the elements by adding setScaleX/Y to the constructor of custom element MagazineCell which extends RelativeLayout:

```
public MagazineCell(Context context) {
    super(context);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.mag_big, null);
    addView(layout);

    this.setScaleX(0.7f);
    this.setScaleY(0.7f);
}
```

I also tried to set the scale in drawChild() of the gallery with no luck. In adapter I'm simply using this class for gallery elements:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MagazineCell cell;
    position = getPosition(position);

    if (null == convertView || convertView.getClass() != MagazineCell.class) {
        cell = new MagazineCell(context);
    } else {
        cell = (MagazineCell) convertView;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Gallery has no special code. I'm using SDK 11 on Acer Iconia TAB A500 running Android 3.1.

Thanks for any hints or comments.

Comment: I met this problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's no way to "trick" Gallery to measure scaled cells with their scaled width. So I just used negative spacing - **setSpacing(-100);** There may be a way via overriding onMeasure method on MagazineCell class and calculate scaled width. But I didn't try this.

Answer (score 0):

after
    this.setScaleX(0.7f);
    this.setScaleY(0.7f);
add
    this.setPivotX(0);
    this.setPivotY(0);